# Blending two images using OpenCV with different shapes and position

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I need to blend two images with different types.

I have several saved objects with a transparent background and I would like to add them over a background. However, their size is smaller than the size of the background and I would like to put them in random positions.

For example: I have the picture of a bedroom as a background and would like to put a refrigerator (smaller than the bedroom) in a random position of the bedroom.

However, as the code is using the weight of the images I don't know how to define this blend in a certain position of the background image and how to work with the two images in different dimensions.

I'm using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def blend_transparent(face_img, overlay_t_img):
    # Split out the transparency mask from the colour info
    overlay_img = overlay_t_img[:,:,:3] # Grab the BRG planes
    overlay_mask = overlay_t_img[:,:,3:]  # And the alpha plane

    # Again calculate the inverse mask
    background_mask = 255 - overlay_mask

    # Turn the masks into three channel, so we can use them as weights
    overlay_mask = cv2.cvtColor(overlay_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    background_mask = cv2.cvtColor(background_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    # Create a masked out face image, and masked out overlay
    # We convert the images to floating point in range 0.0 - 1.0
    face_part = (face_img * (1 / 255.0)) * (background_mask * (1 / 255.0))
    overlay_part = (overlay_img * (1 / 255.0)) * (overlay_mask * (1 / 255.0))

    # And finally just add them together, and rescale it back to an 8bit integer image    
    return np.uint8(cv2.addWeighted(face_part, 255.0, overlay_part, 255.0, 0.0))
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Select a ROI (region of interest) of the background that is the same size as the image you want to overlay (using numpy array indexing). Use that for the blending, and then store the result in the same position.

Comment: It's called [overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopencv%5D+overlay).